# Finding multiple variables to make a function continuous

Tags: piecewise-continuity

Given the function:
[image: f(x) is 3 times the square of x minus 9 times x plus 6, divided by 1 minus a times x; if x is less than 1, or 3 times the sqrt of x plus b times times (x minus 1) if x is greater than or equal to 1]

give values for $a$ and $b$ in order that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=1$

I can't figure out how to calculate $a$. When $x$ is 1 the numerator is 0,. How do I get the limits on either side to be equal?

Comment: $a$ can't be the reciprocal of $x$ that's about the only restriction without reformulation.

Comment: For $a=1$ you might want to use L'hospitals rule to calculate the limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $b(x-1)$ is always $0$ at $x=1$, $b$ is arbitrary. Then we must achieve

$$\lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 1^-}3\frac{(x-1)(x-2)}{1-ax}=\lim_{x\to 1^-}3\frac{1-x}{1-ax}=3$$ and this works with $a=1$ (any other value of $a$ makes $f(1^-)=0$).

Answer (score 0):

Hints: compute $\lim_{x \to 1+0}f(x)$ and $f(1)$. Furthermore compute $\lim_{x \to 1-0}f(x)$ in the cases $a=1$ and $a \ne 1.$

$f$ is continuous at $x=1 \iff \lim_{x \to 1+0}f(x)=f(1)=\lim_{x \to 1-0}f(x).$

Comment: OK, I'm a little bit lost, can you help me with that? Isn't f(1)=3? How do we solve for lim→1−0() to be =3?

Answer (score 0):

OK, got it. f(1)=3 As well as lim→1+0()=3. For the lim→1−0() we assume a=1 which allows us to factor the denominator to -(x-2). The numerator is factored to 3(x-2)(x-1). The (x-2) in the numerator and denominator cancel out which leaves us with 3(x-1)/-1. Solving for x=1 we get 3 which confirms continuity for a=1.
If ≠1 we would not be able to factor and would always get 0 in the numerator so a could only be 1. 
b can be anything because we would always get 3 for f(1) and lim→1+0()